# WordPress Category Pagination

Tags: wordpress, pagination, categories

I have been to this problem for 2 days already. The layout and pagination comes out with no problem but when I clicked 'Next' or the number, it doesn't work. This is the pagination of my category page. I am actually editing category.php so please do check the link below. Thanks!

LINK: http://pastebin.com/sMmGadzV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is fine.
I put your code into my own theme `category.php` file and pagination is working.

Please check your post reading limit. You set your post limit on a page is `5`, If your posts are less than `5` , Pagination won't show,  and how much posts on your blog .

And after all if your problem don't solved than please check your `category.php` coding

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine..! just install this plugin

> http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-paginate/screenshots/

And replace text  `posts_nav_link` with plugin given code.

I hope this will help you